# How to fix an XMLHttpRequest.open() returning code 0 when the contents are apparently correct?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am attempting to make a call to an API using the link that has been automatically generated by the developers. I am using the XMLHttpRequest.open() method based on the tutorial at https://javascript.info/xmlhttprequest. However, when I try to make a call, the only status I am able to achieve is "0", which I think means something on my end(?).

I have tried different links to other APIs, including ones that don't require anything besides the plain link, and have gotten the same response, which means that it's not necessarily something to do with the API I want, and other solutions (such as $.JSON().done()) aren't cooperating either.

My very minimal code:

```html
<button onclick="getEndDate()">Click Me</button>

<script>
  function getEndDate() {
  alert("in function");
  // create request
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
  alert("request made");
  // request data from API (API link automatically generated)
request.open('GET', 'https://holidayapi.com/v1/holidays?key=validkey&country=US&year=2018&pretty', true)
  alert("request opened"+ request.status);
  // send request (?)
  request.send()
  alert("request sent");
request.onload = function() {
  alert("request loaded");
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
  // If we receive a valid code
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach(holiday => {
      alert(holiday.name, holiday.date);
    })
  } else {
    alert('error');
  }
  }
}
</script>
```

I expect to be able to run through all of the alerts at the very least, however I can only get to "request sent", meaning there is a problem with loading the result of the request. In the status, as mentioned before, I would be expecting a 200 instead of 0.

Am I approaching this entirely the wrong way? If so, what way should I be trying to call the API?

Comment: your code works fine ... except ... `data` isn't an array ... `data.holidays` is the array you want ... the status you are alerting is BEFORE the request is even made - here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5610r2k9/) using console.log instead of alert, to show your code is making and receiving the request without any issue

Comment: P.S. probably wasn't a good idea showing your API key like that

Comment: Start trying to make [_fetch_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) happen ~ `fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => { ... })`. Otherwise, I recommend setting the `onload` handler **before** calling `send()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest's `send()` method behaves in a somewhat synchronous manner. Parts of its behavior may or may not be asynchronous (depending on `.open()'s` async flag) but parts of it is definitely synchronous.

Setting up event handlers (`onload`, `onreadystatechange` etc) are done synchronously. This was how Internet Explorer implemented it and since Microsoft invented XMLHttpRequest it's how the specification demands it to be implemented.

Specifically, [step 5 of the spec for `.send()`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send()-method) requires it to:

> 5. If one or more event listeners are registered on the associated XMLHttpRequestUpload object, then set upload listener flag.

So setting up event listeners is done before the `.send()` function returns, not when a response is received from the network.

So in your code you have:

```
request.send(); // send will now check if it has .onload registered and
                // set up appropriate event listeners.

request.onload = function() { /* ... */ } // too late, this is ignored
```

You need to set any event listeners either via `.onload`, `.onreadystatechange` etc. or via `.addEventListener('load', ...)` before calling `.send()`.

Note that in **all official examples** of XMLHttpRequest usage (the whatwg spec, MDN, MSDN etc.) the event handlers are **always** set up before `.open()` so I suggest you do the same even though technically the spec allows you to do it after `.open()` but before `.send()`:

```
request.onload = function() { /* ... */ }
request.open('GET', url, true);
request.send();
```

There have been (I don't know if there currently is) some browser versions in the past that allowed you to set event handlers after `.send()` because they use standard EventEmitters instead of following the spec. But these implementations technically does not comply with the standard even though it feels right.